# Adding ADFS to existing AD Application

Tags: active-directory, asp.net, adfs

We have an existing .NET application that uses Active Directory to authenticate users and search for user/OU data using DirectorySearcher object. Our customer has several AD servers and would like our existing application to authenticate/search from a single endpoint. Can we leverage our existing application by adding ADFS service to the customer's network to authenticate/search across several AD servers? Our application uses .NET System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearch object using LDAP queries to authenticate and search for user/OU data.

Comment: Each DC holds a copy of the AD database. Why would you need to search more than one DC?

Comment: The customer wants to group the users within the application that would span multiple Active Directories/DC.

Comment: So you mean multiple AD Forests or multiple AD Domains in the same AD Forest?

Comment: This is a international customer across continents, I believe multiple AD Forests, we are in the midst of getting more information on the specific topology.

Answer (score 0):

No, ADFS is a tool to create a trust between two identity providers (e.g. Active Directory) or an identity provider and a service provider (e. g. your application). It is used for authentication only. It does not offer any functionality to access objects between the trust parties.

As your goal is to search directories, ADFS will not help you there.

Comment: Good to know. We could possibly still use ADFS as authentication is a primary requirement.